# JavaScript Function to return a gradient of 2 sets of coords returns 0 ONLY when calling from specific function

Tags: javascript, html, html5-canvas

I have a function in Javascript to return a gradient of 2 sets of coordinates. The coordinates are retrieved from two clicks on a canvas element. This is done for 2 lines.

The gradient function works normally:

```
    function calcGradient(x1,y1,x2,y2){
        return ((y2-y1)/(x2-x1));
}
```

It works if I call it normally:

```
console.log(calcGradient(0, 0, 3, 6)); // Returns 2
```

Even decimals, when I thought *that* was the problem:

```
console.log(calcGradient(0, 0, 3.2324, 6.969)); // Returns 2.1559831703997028
```

But when I call it so:

```
function updateLineStats() {
    var p_line1_formula = document.querySelector("#formula_line-1 span");
    var p_line2_formula = document.querySelector("#formula_line-2 span");

    var p_line1_gradient = document.querySelector("#gradient_line-1 span");
    var p_line2_gradient = document.querySelector("#gradient_line-2 span");

    var p_line1_length = document.querySelector("#length_line-1 span");
    var p_line2_length = document.querySelector("#length_line-2 span");

    var p_isIntersecting = document.querySelector("#isIntersecting");

    var elementDir = [
        [p_line1_formula, p_line2_formula],
        [p_line1_gradient, p_line2_gradient],
        [p_line1_length, p_line2_length]
    ];

    lines.forEach(function (lineData, i) {
        if(!(lineData[0].includes(null) || lineData[1].includes(null))) {

            elementDir[1][i].innerHTML = calcGradient(
                lineData[0][0],
                lineData[1][1],
                lineData[1][0],
                lineData[1][1]);

            elementDir[2][i].innerHTML = calcLength(
                lineData[0][0],
                lineData[1][1],
                lineData[1][0],
                lineData[1][1]);
        }
    })
}
```

It returns 0 onto the `<p>` elements in question.

The length of the lines works.
The `formula` variables are not used yet.

The canvas is 500x500, and so the values are anywhere between that.

Comment: Where do you initialize `lines` array?

Comment: You use `lineData[1][1]` twice when calling `calcGradient` and `calcLength`. Is that intentional?

Comment: @Marlos the array is as follows: ```var lines =[[[null,null],[null, bull]],[[null,null],[null,null]]]. It's two lines, 2 sets of points each. When the clicks are made I update each line accordingly.

Comment: @Zufeng no it's not. I'll check it out

Comment: You should provide the `lines` initialisation code *inside* your question. It is essential. If what you say in comments is right, then the condition `!(lineData[0].includes(null) || lineData[1].includes(null))` is never true, and so the function `calcGradient` is never called. With a minimal debugging effort and stepping through the code using dev-tools, you would have spotted that yourself.

Answer (score 0):

I have created an example with sample data to show you how it works. If you have more than 2 sets of coordinates then either overwrite the existing ones or create new elements dynamically and add them to the DOM.

```js
     function calcGradient(x1,y1,x2,y2){
        return ((y2-y1)/(x2-x1));
     }
     
     function calcLength(x1,y1,x2,y2){
        return ((y2-y1)/(x2-x1));
     }

     let lines = [ 
                   [ [0,0],
                     [3,6] ],
                   [ [0,0],
                     [3.2324,6.969] ]
                 ];
       
       
        var p_line1_formula = document.querySelector("#formula_line-1 span");
        var p_line2_formula = document.querySelector("#formula_line-2 span");

        var p_line1_gradient = document.querySelector("#gradient_line-1 span");
        var p_line2_gradient = document.querySelector("#gradient_line-2 span");

        var p_line1_length = document.querySelector("#length_line-1 span");
        var p_line2_length = document.querySelector("#length_line-2 span");

        var elementDir = [
            [p_line1_formula, p_line2_formula], //elementDir[0][0] , elementDir[0][1]
            [p_line1_gradient, p_line2_gradient], //elementDir[1][0] , elementDir[1][1]
            [p_line1_length, p_line2_length] //elementDir[2][0] , elementDir[2][1]
        ];
        let counter = 1;
        lines.forEach( el=>{
            //checks if the sub array is null, counter should not be greater than 2 because it's the length of elementDir
            if(el != null && counter < elementDir.length){
                //gets the sub array at position 1 and the element with index 0 => p_line1_gradient
                elementDir[counter][0].innerHTML = calcGradient(
                    el[0][0],
                    el[0][1],
                    el[1][0],
                    el[1][1]);
                
                //gets the sub array at position 1 and the element with index 1 => p_line2_gradient
                elementDir[counter][1].innerHTML = calcLength(
                    el[0][0],
                    el[0][1],
                    el[1][0],
                    el[1][1]);
            }

            counter++;
        });
```

```html
<div id="gradient_line-1"><span></span></div>
    <div id="gradient_line-2"><span></span></div>
    <div id="length_line-1"><span></span></div>
    <div id="length_line-2"><span></span></div>
```